# What is difference between AcquireTokenForClient vs AcquireTokenSilent In MSAL.NET?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, adal, azure-authentication

I have started using MSAL.
now I have 2 implementation of getting token from MSAL #

```
 ##First one is##
app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

## another one is ##
 app.AcquireTokenSilent
```

what is difference between them ?

Comment: In other situations, I have found and written methods that are not allowed to show a UI and fail silently for example if the user had to enter a password. Used for background operation. Could be something like that.

Comment: its more with back end api to api call when we are generating token for api to api call

Answer (score 3):

AcquireTokenSilent() is for **user based authentication** and AcquireTokenForClient() is for **app-only authentication** (used in service to service calls, for example).

The [AcquireTokenSilent](https://Reference:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.clientapplicationbase.acquiretokensilent?view=azure-dotnet) needs an account parameter when called, so it can search the user token cache for a valid accessToken.

The [AcquireTokenForClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication.acquiretokenforclient?view=azure-dotnet) only needs a scope parameter - there is no user context involved, the accessToken is acquired on behalf of the application itself.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently i refer this but where they mention